# JBoss default HTML errors and REST webservice application

Tags: rest, jboss

I have a REST based webservice that was originally deployed to WebSphere and errors were being returned properly as we expected (HTTP Status code plus a text message in the response body of the details of the error). But once deployed to JBoss, those text error messages became wrapped in HTML by JBoss, I'm assuming because we don't have any error-page definitions in our web.xml (why would we in a webservice application?).

How do I get around this? There should be a straightforward way to tell JBoss to stop trying to "pretty up" my error messages. Please help. Need a solution.

Answer (score -1):

possibly try making sure your content type is not text/html, just send plaintext

Comment: Tried that. Didn't change anything

Comment: Basically we need to make sure that no exceptions trickle out of our application. If they do, then JBoss will end up wrapping them in html to display in a browser page. We now have exception handlers (using spring error handler pattern) that handle all types of exceptions so we don't let any exceptions bubble out of our app. Our exception handlers/mappers will handle returning the proper JSON response.